# Cannot create QScrollArea with QWidget and QVBoxLayout to QWidget with QVBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have this code:

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def init_gui(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.new1()
        self.new2()

        self.showMaximized()

    def create_scroll_area(self):
        scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        widget = QWidget()
        scroll_area.setWidget(widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        button = QPushButton("Ahoj")
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.layout.addLayout(layout)

    def new1(self):
        self.create_scroll_area()

    def new2(self):
        self.create_scroll_area()
```

I get this error message:

```
QLayout::addChildLayout: layout "" already has a parent
```

What's wrong?

Who is layout's parent? Widget? I also tried `self.widget` instead of `widget` and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.init_gui()
    def init_gui(self):        
        self.create_scroll_area()
        self.showMaximized()        
    def create_scroll_area(self):
        scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        widget = QWidget()        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()        
        button = QPushButton("Ahoj")        
        layout.addWidget(button)
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        scroll_area.setWidget(widget)   
        self.setLayout(layout)
def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Let's revise from A to Z.

**1 to write self.init_gui() in __init__ constructor.**

If you don't do it, you can't execute `init_gui` method at the first time.

**2.`setLayout()` or `setWidget()` should be written at the last place at least.**

In python, we prepare the things we want to show, and set them on the mainwidget, and show them at the last time.

**3.please pay attention to self.layout name.**

Widget has originally `setLayout()` method. and `layout()` method.
If you make self.layout = ***, you crush the original method of `QWidget`.

**4. it may as well delete `new1` and `new2` method.**

please call them directly.

**5. please look `create_scroll_area` method.**

You make three widget.`QScrollArea`,`QWidget`,`QPushButton`.
and make a layout object.and you set the layout into `QWidget`.
But you set the `QWidget` before the widget set the layout.
It is not good order for coding.

You make `QPushButton` but the button doesn't belong to any widget.
Because you set the button on the `self.layout` certainly, but if you want to show it, you must `setLayout(self.layout)` at the last position.

Comment: 3. I want QV Layout and inner two QV layouts. It was reason I don't use originally setLayout() method but create self.layout and add layouts to it.

Comment: @John Doe Ok, I forget to say, scrollArea also doesn't belong to any widget.

Comment: You mean that you make  a `QVBoxLayout` and make two QVBoxLayouts into it?Even if you don't use `setLayout()` method, you don't have to crush `self.layout`.I think it is better you name it as other name.

Comment: From your code, you make only a `QVBoxLayout`... How do you attempt to make two `QVBoxLayout`?By calling `create_scroll_area` method two times?

Comment: Thanks for help! I little edited my code and created new post, please check it = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773492/simplify-my-code-one-function-to-create-is-used-by-other-functions .

Comment: @Johon Doe I understand you want to solve your problem speedy,but you may as well finish each question completely. I have mind in accepting your comment as you like if you have questions about this question.If you solved your problem by my answer, please accept my answer once.

Comment: @John Doe, I accept your comment as you solved this problem, but you have other problems.I accept your reward as a fee of writing my answer.thanks.

Comment: Can you help me with other problems? Link below.